# Run : Apache:j-meter in linuxServer as GUI or any other approach

Tags: apache, user-interface, batch-file, server, jmeter

I have apache j meter installed in my local machine which has .bat file .sh executable files in it, to run in gui mode in windows, now i want to execute it on server which is in linux environment, how can i run as gui mode in server?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not be running JMeter in GUI mode, you should use GUI mode for tests development and/or debugging. When it comes to executing the load test itself make sure you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

In regards to how you can proceed there are several options:

1. Develop the test under Windows, transfer the .jmx file to Linux box using [pscp](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/pscp.exe), [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), etc.
2. Develop the test under Windows and run JMeter in distributed mode, i.e. have JMeter Master on Windows and JMeter Slave on Linux, see [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) guide for more details
3. You can install X Window Server implementation on Windows box (i.e. [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) or [Cygwin/X](https://x.cygwin.com/) and use [X forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely) so you will run JMeter on linux and see its GUI on Windows.

Comment: Thank you.I was doing the same as well, but it seems time consuming. i have a doubt now, can we generate the .jmx file without using GUI i mean not doing it in windows and then copying to linux, is it possible to generate it in linux directly.Thanks in Advance for anything that you assist.